# problem in updating CM12 nightly on Moto G XT1033

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-moto-g, twrp, rom-update

I have installed **CM12 Falcon nightly build** on my Moto G 1st Generation XT1033 after installing CM12 I tried to update using **Settings->About Phone->Cynogenmod updates** first time it successfully installed CM updates but after that I am not able to install latest updates.

The system update is crashing in Recovery mode message saying
unable to install from zip

What should I do?

Note : I am using TWRP Recovery and not CM Recovery.

Comment: Did you uncheck the option to Update Recovery With System Updates in CM Developer Settings?

Comment: Do I have to charge my recovery for that???

Comment: Did you mean "change" instead of "charge"?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's change

Comment: There should be a recovery log in the twrp or the root folder of your sd card. can you upload that so we can check the problem?

Comment: I checked the twrp folder in my phone, it's empty

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stopgap measure to keep your phone updated:

1) Nandroid backup. **Necessary**

2) Get latest CM12 falcon zip.

3) Copy zip to SD card.

4) Reboot to TWRP.

5) Wipe `/cache` and `/system`.

6) Dirty-flash ( common parlance for flashing without wiping `userdata`) the zip.

7) Cross your fingers and hope it works.

8) If it doesn't, there's your Nandroid backup. Now try a clean flash (in step 5, also wipe `/data`.

9) It should work (it's like installing a new ROM).

10) The next time onwards, download the OTA zip yourself, compare checksums of the files, copy the OTA zip to your SD card, flash the **OTA zip** without **wiping anything**.